# Should I be tracking slowly changing dimensions in a Relational/transational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, data-warehouse, etl, dimensional-modeling

Let's use the example of a Human Resources database.  The transactional database that the HR personnel use on a day-to-day basis handles all of the hiring and firing that takes place on a daily basis.  There is also a Dimensional Data Warehouse that pulls from that transactional database.

assuming that latency is sufficiently low, which of the following arguments would be considered "best practice"?

1)  the Transactional database should only have to keep track of how that data currently is.  it shouldn't have to keep track of slowly changing data (For example, the history of which managers a specific employee has had, how his salary has evolved over time, etc.).  The ETL Process should detect changes in the transitional database, and update slowly changing dimensions in the data warehouse.

2) The transactional database is more than capable of tracking it's own historical information.  If something were to ever change twice in between ETL sessions, you would lose the first change forever.  The main purpose of the Dimensional database is for efficient query performance in reports, so it is still doing it's job.  This also allows the ETL process to be faster and simpler.

I feel like both arguments have merits, and if they are both valid arguments, I am happy to simply choose between them.

Am I missing something that isn't being taken into consideration?

Are one of the arguments flat out wrong?

Comment: What you're missing are the **business requirements**. Do the users need historical data? Also, grab a copy of *The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Complete Guide to Dimensional Modeling* - there's an entire chapter on dimensional modeling of HR data in the book.

Answer (score 3):

I think what @marek-grzenkowicz said is correct. If the business requirements of the HR transactional/operational system state that a history of changes are required, then they belong in the transactional/operational system. Likewise, if the business requirements state that this history (or perhaps a history at a different level of granularity) are required, the warehouse would store that as well. It is possible that the histories may be stored in both systems.

I too recommend "The Data Warehouse Toolkit". I'm reading it now and it seems to have a lot of time- and field-tested design patterns for modeling your data. The 3rd edition of this book just came out a couple weeks ago.